# using pin instrumentation in ubuntu: error

Tags: installation, compilation-target

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [No such file or directory? But the file exists!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists)

I have used pin in ubuntu Linux with

```
3.0.0-19-generic #33-Ubuntu SMP  x86_64; gcc version 4.6
```

and also in redhat

```
2.6.18-308.el5 #1 SMP  x86_64; gcc version 4.7
```

However, I am trying to use it in ubuntu:

```
Linux info 2.6.35-32-server #65-Ubuntu SMP x86_64
```

and getting error:

```
/pin-2.10-45467-gcc.3.4.6-ia32_intel64-linux/ia32/bin/pinbin: No such file or directory
```

The pin binary uses:

```
machine=`uname -m`

if [ $machine == "ia64" ] 
then
    exec "$origin"/ia64/bin/pinbin "${@}"
else
    exec "$origin"/ia32/bin/pinbin -p64 "$origin"/intel64/bin/pinbin "${@}"
fi
```

which surprises me, since machine is x86_64. I don't know why it compares with ia64.
Can anyone help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have 32-bit support installed? I think you have the same problem as [No such file or directory? But the file exists!](http://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/133460#133460)

Comment: Thanks. Actually my problem is same as, I just found out, http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/pinheads/message/5654. Only thing is that I don't have root right to machine. So I can't still solve it. Can you please suggest something.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you ask your system administrator to install `ia32-libs`. This is likely to be useful to other people besides you. If your sysadmin won't budge, it's possible to install everything in your home directory, but it's a hassle.