# Java install does not work - no such file or directory

Tags: software-installation, java, jdk

I am unable to run java after downloading it. I'd appreciate troubleshooting help.

Info:
⠀Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
⠀Acer Aspire V5 with AMD A4 processor
⠀Used Oracle 64-bit Linux version
⠀jdk-8u45-linux-i586.tar.gz

```
$ java -version
bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

$ update-alternatives --display java
java - auto mode
  link currently points to /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java - priority 2
Current 'best' version is '/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java'.
```

The file is there, and it appears to have correct permissions:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5730 Apr 10 10:53 /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is a 32 bit executable even though it is from a 64 bit jdk for Linux.
I found the solution here:
[No such file or directory? But the file exists!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists)

Using file [suggested by Gilles](https://askubuntu.com/a/133460/527764) confirmed the problem.
[The answer by Avinash Raj](https://askubuntu.com/a/454452/527764) was specific and fixed my install.