# (FlexNet Publisher) No such file or directory when trying to run Elf 32-bit LSB executable

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I'm new in Linux. I got a issue of No such file or directory when I ran a program that exists really. I checked this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists) 
I tried the `/opt/FNPLicenseServerManager/lmadmin` command, I got:

```
sudo: unable to execute /opt/FNPLicenseServerManager/lmadmin: No such file or directory
```

Then I typed 'file lmadmin'

```
/opt/FNPLicenseServerManager/lmadmin: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-lsb.so.3, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, stripped
```

As I saw that it's a 32-bit program, I installed the i386 architecture. Then I restart again, still got the same 'No such file' error:

Then I guessed that it's a executable programme that link to something. I ran `ls -la`:

```
drwxrw-r-- 9 user root    4096 juin  12 22:41 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 root        root    4096 mai    9 17:02 ..
drwxrwxr-x 2 user root    4096 mai    9 17:02 conf
drwxrwxr-x 2 user root    4096 mai    9 17:02 demo
drwxrwxr-x 5 user root    4096 juin  12 18:20 examples
drwxr-xr-x 6 user root    4096 juin  12 22:41 jre
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root 1818850 mars  31  2016 libcrypto.so.1.0.0
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root  721280 mars  31  2016 libhasp_linux_i686.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root  135707 mars  31  2016 liblber-2.4.so.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root  934541 mars  31  2016 libldap-2.4.so.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root   97704 mars  31  2016 libsasl2.so.2
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root  414693 mars  31  2016 libssl.so.1.0.0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user sudo 9980532 mai    4  2016 lmadmin
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root    1726 mars  31  2016 README-swidtag-lmadmin.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root    9047 avril  4  2014 regid.2009-06.com.flexerasoftware_2e0efef8-e286-4f84-85bc-cb67687c7706.swidtag
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root    9057 avril  4  2014 regid.2009-06.com.flexerasoftware_643a523d-3ea1-4b01-a0c3-e47e9f5330d3.swidtag
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root    8979 avril 11  2017 regid.2009-06.com.flexerasoftware_b80318ea-8cfd-46c5-96bb-db84954d9d5a.swidtag
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root    8979 mars  31  2016 regid.2009-06.com.flexerasoftware_becd1b9a-f421-4c4d-8f4b-c113cfa33b71.swidtag
-rw-r--r-- 1 user root    9047 avril  4  2014 regid.2009-06.com.flexerasoftware_d4410038-ff9f-4cbd-9208-6250cc2ea857.swidtag
drwxr--r-- 3 user root    4096 mai    9 17:03 uninstall
drwxrwxr-x 8 user root    4096 mai    9 17:02 web
drwxrwxr-x 2 user root    4096 mai    9 17:02 wsdl
```

So it doesn't link to something.
Moreover, I used `ldd lmadmin` like this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/344533/no-such-file-or-directory-error-in-bash-but-the-file-exists). I have all the libraries needed apart of linux-gate.so.1:

```
    linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xf7f2b000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7ee8000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7e93000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7e76000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7cc0000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf7cba000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7cb1000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /opt/FNPLicenseServerManager/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0xf7c56000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /opt/FNPLicenseServerManager/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0xf7ad1000)
    libldap-2.4.so.2 => /opt/FNPLicenseServerManager/libldap-2.4.so.2 (0xf7a91000)
    liblber-2.4.so.2 => /opt/FNPLicenseServerManager/liblber-2.4.so.2 (0xf7a84000)
    libcrypt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libcrypt.so.1 (0xf7a52000)
    /lib/ld-lsb.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f2d000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv.so.2 (0xf7a39000)
    libsasl2.so.2 => /opt/FNPLicenseServerManager/libsasl2.so.2 (0xf7a1f000)
```

I don't know why I still get the 'No such file error'

Could somebody kindly help me, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figure it out myself. Several things should be check:

1. If the lmadmin is a dangling link
2. If the lmadmin really exists
3. Check that all the discrepancies are installed and found (have all a 
   directory and a 8bit address loaded in the RAM)

If all those are checked and it couldn't still be run (which is my case):

4. You need to do `file lmadmin` on the same folder to check if lmadmin is written in 32bit architecture while your PC is on 64bit. If so, install the 32bit-architecture library depanding on your Linux distribution.
5. (Which fix my problem) Install also the LSB (try both tiny/capital letter with apt-get) library. My Ubuntu version is strangly missing this or not up to date.