# ./words part of Legible Latin does not run under Ubuntu 18.04.1

Tags: command-line, 18.04, package-management

Installed XUbuntu 18.04.1. Installed Linux version of Legible latin (http://www.perlingua.com/LatinHome/Legible/). Under 12.04--16.04 it was enough to go to the "parts" subfolder and run

```
./words
```

from terminal (and a command-line dictionary Latin-to-English appeared). Now it results in:

```
bash: ./words: No such file or directory
```

Tried to find the answer online but to no avail. Apparently the problem is more general than just running this exact application but I do not know how to properly generalise it.

**UPDATE 1:**

```
~/Programs/Legible Latin Linux/parts$ ls -l
total 23592
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username   35357 Dec 10  2010 ADDONS.LAT
drwxrwxr-x 2 username username    4096 Aug 10 23:57 Authors
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 6860520 Dec 10  2010 DICTFILE.GEN
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 1770956 Dec 10  2010 engwords
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 7349628 Dec 10  2010 EWDSFILE.GEN
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username   40431 Dec 10  2010 free_latin.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username   13786 Dec 10  2010 FreeLatin.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username   19684 Dec 10  2010 INDXFILE.GEN
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username  108000 Dec 10  2010 INFLECTS.SEC
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username      80 Dec 10  2010 latin
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username  948631 Apr  3  2013 Legible.gz
-rwxrwxr-x 1 username username 2994961 Oct 16  2013 legible.rev
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username    5312 Dec 10  2010 README
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username 2882736 Dec 10  2010 STEMFILE.GEN
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username   11565 Dec 10  2010 UNIQUES.LAT
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username     575 Oct 11  2013 WORD.MOD
-rwxr-xr-x 1 username username  876459 Dec 10  2010 words
-rw-r--r-- 1 username username  204283 Dec 10  2010 wordsdoc.htm
```

**UPDATE 2:** I tried `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and got `i386`. Following the advice found on the link you provided I tried to install `ia32-libs` but it was not possible:

```
Package ia32-libs is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
lib32ncurses5 lib32z1
    
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate
```

I installed `lib32ncurses5` and the situation changed:

```
$ ./words
./words: error while loading shared libraries: libgcc_s.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

but to no good anyway.

`libgcc_s.so.1` cannot be installed with `apt-get install`.

**UPDATE 3:** Solved by installing `sudo apt-get install lib32gcc-4.8-dev` (based on the solutions proposed here: [How to Compile 32-bit Apps on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355436/how-to-compile-32-bit-apps-on-64-bit-ubuntu))

Comment: It works fine on my Lubuntu 18.04 machine, exactly like you describe it – did you extract the tarball correctly (`tar -xf LegibleLatinLinux.tar.gz`)?

Comment: No, I tried 

    tar -zxvf LegibleLatinLinux.tar.gz

and retried using just xf, but the result is the same (No such file, etc.).

Comment: Since your permissions appear to be set correctly for `words`, you may be running into the third possible issue mentioned in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/133460/304156). If you do `file words`, the `words` file is an "ELF 32-bit LSB executable", but you may not have support for that kind of executable on your system. As far as I know, support for i386 is default in 18.04.1, but you may want to check `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` if you are on an amd64 version of Xubuntu.

Comment: Tried to follow the advice at the link you provided. Updated the question (for the news are too long). The problem remains unsolved.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was solved by installing first `lib32ncurses5` and then `lib32gcc-4.8-dev` (based on the solutions proposed here: [How to Compile 32-bit Apps on 64-bit Ubuntu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22355436/how-to-compile-32-bit-apps-on-64-bit-ubuntu))