# not able to run a downloaded program file in ubuntu 18.04 terminal

Tags: command-line, 32-bit

when I try running a program file downloaded in terminal ubuntu 18.04 by `./filename.exec Input.data` as per the program user manual, it says no such file or directory, but when I do `ls`, `ls -l` , it shows the file in executable state, but still does not run...why? can anyone help me, being a newbie in bioinformatics.
The program file contains executable file and input files.

```
$ pwd
/home/ubuntu/Downloads/program_directory
$ file ./filename.exec Input.data
./filename.exec: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-, for GNU/Linux 2.6.15, BuildID[sha1]=41506b3ff2b0a8a1a10c2d856fc68be667a93df3, not stripped` 
Input.data:                  ASCII text
$ ./filename.exec Input.data
bash:No such file or directory
$ ldd sRNAscanner_Ubuntu10.exec | grep not
    not a dynamic executable
```

I even tried running as root, but same response

Comment: It is 32-bit executable, while system is possibly 64-bit. Some libraries may be missed. Please open terminal in the directory with this executable and run command `ldd filename.exec | grep not` - add this output to the question by [editing it](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1252116/edit).

Comment: Can you please give us a link for the program to download and try executing it to find what's wrong?

Comment: Does it actually say `interpreter /lib/ld-` in the output of `file`? Or is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: @muru Yes it says the same

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such file or directory? But the file exists!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists) See [Avinash's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/454452/816190).

Comment: Thank u so much everyone who helped me...

Answer (score 1):

You have to start by installing main 32-bit C library:

```
sudo apt-get install libc6:i386
```