# `-bash: No such file or directory` When there is very mutch is file there

Tags: bash, filesystem, raspberrypi, arm, filename

I am trying to install [sdr++](https://www.sdrpp.org/), but I dont think that matters. after installing the nightly apt package on my rpi 4, I attempted to run the main bianary `sdrpp` but got a file not found error:

```bash
pi@sdr:~ $ /usr/bin/sdrpp
-bash: /usr/bin/sdrpp: No such file or directory
pi@sdr:~ $ ls -li /usr/bin/sdrpp
43166 -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 8144 Jul 23 23:58 /usr/bin/sdrpp
```

- As far as I can tell there arent any strange chars (ѕ vs s, diffrent chars but look alike)
- These two commands were exicuted shortly after one another, so its not like the file was suddenly created
- Still happens after a restart
- I think I got this same bug a long time ago trying to run rust in a replit, I never fixed it.
- File reports it as a `ELF 32-bit LSB executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3, BuildID[sha1]=c4fea3dbc91de8553d404ed70b214efe2a234f39, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped` and im pretty sure that's accurate

Other info:

```bash
pi@sdr:~ $ uname -a
Linux sdr 6.1.21-v8+ #1642 SMP PREEMPT Mon Apr  3 17:24:16 BST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux
pi@sdr:~ $ whereis sdrpp
sdrpp: /usr/bin/sdrpp /usr/lib/sdrpp /usr/share/sdrpp
pi@sdr:~ $ ls -li /usr/bin/sdrpp /usr/lib/sdrpp /usr/share/sdrpp
 43166 -rwxr-xr-x 1 pi pi 8144 Jul 23 23:58 /usr/bin/sdrpp

/usr/lib/sdrpp:
[...]

/usr/share/sdrpp:
[...]
pi@sdr:~ $
```

( `[...]` indicates the output was manualy trimmed by me )

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such file or directory? But the file exists!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists)

Comment: I think this is relevant, because you are trying to run a 32-bit executable in a 64-bit system.

Comment: i will try this

Comment: @MechMK1 i suspect this may be an issue on part of sdrpp, as they ship a 32-bit exe that has mandatory 64-bit dependencies.

Comment: What does `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /usr/bin/sdrpp` do? If it says `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` is not found, then you do not have 32-bit support.

Comment: @makerio Would compiling it yourself from source be an option?

Comment: @makerio I would highly recommend compiling from source. The nightly build never worked for me, and it only took ≈ 20 mins on my system. However, I think this question belongs on the Raspberry Pi Stack Exchange.

Comment: @rando I'm so used to posting to Ubuntu i didn't even realize there was a rpi stack exchange. plus, I've been having even more trouble installing sdrpp on 32bit raspbian.

did you use 32 or 64 bit raspbian?

Comment: 64-bit Raspberry Pi OS

Comment: @rando thank you!

Comment: As it seems you've solved your problem, please close this question.

Answer (score 0):

to those coming from google, sorry as i don't have an answer for you.

this problem was circumvented by abandoning sdrpp for a similar program.

- thank you to @rando for noting that i may have been missing a library (and i suspect that that was the issue), suggesting that i compile from source.
- thank you to @MechMk1 for noting that i had attempted to run a 32 bit executable on a 64 bit machine.