# A binary file exists but shell says no such file

Tags: bash, cmake, binary

1. I'm using the Ubuntu in UserLAnd on an android.
2. I just installed from the Android SDK Manager sdkmanager **cmake 3.18.1**.

Now, I can see the cmake executable from its directory `cmake/3.18.1/bin` by`ls`, but when I run `./cmake`, bash returns `bash: ./cmake: No such file or directory`. What went wrong? The full output from console:

```
ubuntu@me:~/cmake/3.18.1/bin$ ls
ccmake  cmake  cpack  ctest  ninja

ubuntu@me:~/cmake/3.18.1/bin$ ./cmake
bash: ./cmake: No such file or directory

ubuntu@me:~/cmake/3.18.1/bin$ file ./cmake
./cmake: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, stripped

ubuntu@me:~/cmake/3.18.1/bin$ ldd ./cmake
        not a dynamic executable

ubuntu@me:~/cmake/3.18.1/bin$ uname -m              
        aarch64
```

Thanks!

Comment: `./` refers to the *current* directory - are you actually executing the command from `cmake/3.18.1/bin`?

Comment: @steeldriver Yes, I am.

Comment: In that case, the binary file likely has the wrong architecture for your system - see for example [Getting "Not found" message when running a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13391/getting-not-found-message-when-running-a-32-bit-binary-on-a-64-bit-system). The output of commands `file ./cmake` and/or `ldd ./cmake` may be diagnostic.

Comment: ... also [No such file or directory? But the file exists!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists)

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks! As far as the output `file` and `ldd` gives me, I'm running on a 32-bit architecture but this `cmake` is 64-bit. The solution is to install 32-bit `cmake` instead, right?

Comment: Is the architecture Intel at all - or is it ARM? check with `uname -m`

Comment: It's `aarch64` .

Comment: That's [ARM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AArch64) and your executable is for Intel and compatible AMD64 64 bit systems ... You'll need a compatible executable, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?arch=arm64&keywords=cmake

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This confusing error, no file found, [is what you get](https://askubuntu.com/a/133460/85695) if you try to run a binary compiled for a different architecture. In your case, you are running on an [AArch64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AArch64) system, on an ARM chip. However, your binary was compiled for [x86-64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64), an architecture used in Intel and AMD chips (possibly others too).

In short, you cannot execute this binary on your system. Instead, you need to download a version compiled for AArch64 or compile it yourself from source.

Comment: This error can also be generated from the linker. If a library isn't located, it will also generate "No such file or directory."

Comment: That's certainly a misleading error message.

Comment: @RonJohn It's not just confusing, [I'd argue that it's a bug](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/execle.html): "
[ENOEXEC]  The new process image file has the appropriate access permission but has an unrecognized format."  Note, though, the caveat: "The exec functions, except for `execlp()` and `execvp()`".  I'd argue that using one of those when the path to the executable is specified is *also* a bug.

Comment: @Christian: Only if the dynamic linker (ELF interpreter `ld.so`) is not found will `execve` itself return `-ENOENT`.  Otherwise the exec will succeed but a later system call will fail.  Use `file`, or `readelf -l ./foo | grep Requesting`, to check the path.    [How does execve call dynamic linker/loader (ld-linux.so.2)](//stackoverflow.com/q/26876247)  Fun fact: on x86-64 Linux, the Binutils default for `ld foo.o -lc` is different from the actual path distros use ([\`bash: ./a.out: No such file or directory\` on running executable produced by \`ld\`](//stackoverflow.com/q/33970159))

Comment: The ELF interpreter for a dynamically linked binary works very much like how the `#!` line works in a script.  I think binfmt-misc also basically works this way, letting things like qemu work as an interpreter for binaries from a different architecture.

Comment: Everyone: please don't discuss the details of how this _should_ work or whether it is a bug in the comments. If your comment is not asking for or providing a clarification to this answer, then please take it elsewhere.

Comment: @terdon: Yes, x86-64 chips have been sold by vendors other than AMD and Intel.  The only one currently selling CPUs is Zhaoxin, according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_x86_manufacturers .  Past vendors include Centaur and Via (who sold their x86-64 division to Zhaoxin I think).  And yes, I'm pretty sure all of these had x86-64 CPUs; the list of 32-bit x86 vendors is way longer; that wiki article unfortunately doesn't distinguish.  TL:DR: you can take out "possibly" or replace with "a few others".