# bash can't find box86 installation

Tags: bash, arm, arm64

I have the free oracle cloud Ampere A1 VPS which is based on arm64 (aarch64) and I wanted to try and use both box86 and box64 to run x86 and x64 apps

Box64 works fine but even after installing Box86 both from the apt mirrors and compiling it myself, even though it is present at /usr/local/bin/box86, I get this error:

```
bash: /usr/local/bin/box86: No such file or directory
```

how can I fix this?

Comment: You've provided no OS/release details; thus we can't currently look up what is expected for your *unstated* release when you install the package (*which is usually the same for all releases; but not always*).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the outputs of `file /usr/local/bin/box86` and `ldd /usr/local/bin/box86`. See also [A binary file exists but shell says no such file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1492286/a-binary-file-exists-but-shell-says-no-such-file)